# Issues a longer xpath expression

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I am having issues with the `urllib` and `lxml.html` modules.

Here is my original code:

```
import urllib  
import lxml.html  
down='http://v.163.com/special/visualizingdata/'  
file=urllib.urlopen(down).read()  
root=lxml.html.document_fromstring(file)
xpath_str="//div[@class='down s-fc3 f-fl']/a"  
urllist=root.xpath(xpath_str)  
for url in urllist:  
  print url.get("href")
```

When run, it returns this output:

```
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/A/7/S8H1TH9A7.mp4  
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/D/9/S8H1ULCD9.mp4  
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/4/P/S8H1UUH4P.mp4  
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/B/V/S8H1V8RBV.mp4  
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/6/E/S8H1VIF6E.mp4  
http://mov.bn.netease.com/movieMP4/2012/12/B/G/S8H1VQ2BG.mp4
```

But, when I change the line

`xpath_str='//div[@class="down s-fc3 f-fl"]//a'`

into

`xpath_str='//div[@class="col f-cb"]//div[@class="down s-fc3 f-fl"]//a'`

that is to say,

```
urllist=root.xpath('//div[@class="col f-cb"]//div[@class="down s-fc3 f-fl"]//a')
```

I do not receive any output. What is the flaw in this code?
it is so strange that the shorter one can work,the longer one can not,they have the same xpath structure!

open the web 'http://v.163.com/special/visualizingdata/' in firefox ,you can see the html structure with firebug.

[image]

Comment: Please post some sample HTML/XML that this is supposed to parse.

Comment: @larsmans the URL from the code, apparently

Comment: @wRAR I'm not going to open that, no idea what it is.

Comment: i have solved myself it is two blank in `div[@class="col  f-cb"]` not one blank in `div[@class="col f-cb"]`.